# Oracle SQL: How to get the nth node between the root and any node in a tree (Optimizing)

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, hierarchy

I'm trying to find the Nth node from the root starting at a given node.  Return the given node if it is less than or equal to the Nth node from the root.  My query works, but it's slow and I'm not happy with it.  Any ideas on how to refactor this to improve performance?

```
test_data
---------
unique_id | lookup_acct_code 
'1'         'leaf-1'
'2'         'stem-2'
'3'         'branch-1'
'4'         'trunk-2'
'5'         'root-1'

linked_accounts
---------------
acct_code | parent_code
'leaf-1'    'stem-1'
'stem-1'    'twig-1'
'twig-1'    'stick-1'
'stick-1'   'branch-1'
'branch-1'  'trunk-1'
'trunk-1'   'root-1'
'root-1'    NULL
'leaf-2'    'stem-2'
'stem-2'    'twig-2'
'twig-2'    'stick-2'
'stick-2'   'branch-2'
'branch-2'  'trunk-2'
'trunk-2'   'root-2'
'root-2'    NULL

SELECT unique_id,
 (SELECT acct_code
  FROM (SELECT acct_code, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY level desc) rn
        FROM linked_accounts
        CONNECT BY acct_code = PRIOR parent_code
        START WITH acct_code = lookup_acct_code)
  WHERE rn <= 3
  ORDER BY rn DESC
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY)    
FROM test_data;

/* Correct output
1   branch-1
2   branch-2
3   branch-1
4   trunk-2
5   root-1
*/
```

Comment: What is "the root"? Your data says it is when `parent_code` is `NULL` but your query does not appear to check for any `NULL` values nor look for accounts that start with `root` so how do you know that you have found the root?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking for - it might help to draw simple diagrams. I would guess that the fastest recursive query for this would use recursive common table expressions, because then the CTE can stop traversing the tree as soon as it hits the Nth node.

Comment: I don't understand. For example "Nth node from the root starting at a given node". What does that mean? **Which** root? Your sample has two. Is it Nth from the root, or Nth starting at a given node? Etc. Please read your question and - honestly - see if you can understand it yourself. If you can't, neither can we. Separately from that: are all your trees *linear* (meaning, no parent ever has more than one child)?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate value up to the n<sup>th</sup> node from the root first (using a recursive sub-query factoring clause instead of a hierarchical query) and then join rather than using a correlated sub-query:

```sql
WITH from_roots ( acct_code, depth, nth_from_root ) AS (
  SELECT acct_code,
         1,
         acct_code
  FROM   linked_accounts
  WHERE  parent_code IS NULL
UNION ALL
  SELECT l.acct_code,
         depth + 1,
         CASE
         WHEN depth >= 3
         THEN nth_from_root
         ELSE l.acct_code
         END
  FROM   linked_accounts l
         INNER JOIN from_roots f
         ON ( f.acct_code = l.parent_code )
)
SELECT unique_id, nth_from_root
FROM   from_roots f
       INNER JOIN test_data d
       ON ( d.lookup_acct_code = f.acct_code )
```

or, you could adapt your query to use `MAX(LEVEL) OVER () - LEVEL + 1` to directly calculate the depth:

```sql
SELECT unique_id,
       ( SELECT acct_code
         FROM   (
           SELECT acct_code, MAX(LEVEL) OVER () - LEVEL + 1 AS depth
           FROM   linked_accounts
           CONNECT BY acct_code = PRIOR parent_code
           START WITH acct_code = lookup_acct_code
         )
         WHERE depth <= 3
         ORDER BY depth DESC
         FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
       ) AS nth_node
FROM   test_data;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( unique_id, lookup_acct_code ) AS
SELECT '1',         'leaf-1'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2',         'stem-2'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3',         'branch-1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4',         'trunk-2'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '5',         'root-1'   FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE linked_accounts ( acct_code, parent_code ) AS
SELECT 'leaf-1',    'stem-1'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'stem-1',    'twig-1'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'twig-1',    'stick-1'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'stick-1',   'branch-1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'branch-1',  'trunk-1'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'trunk-1',   'root-1'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'root-1',    NULL       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'leaf-2',    'stem-2'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'stem-2',    'twig-2'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'twig-2',    'stick-2'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'stick-2',   'branch-2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'branch-2',  'trunk-2'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'trunk-2',   'root-2'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'root-2',    NULL       FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> ```
> UNIQUE_ID | NTH_FROM_ROOT
> :-------- | :------------
> 1         | branch-1     
> 2         | branch-2     
> 3         | branch-1     
> 4         | trunk-2      
> 5         | root-1
> ```

You would need to profile all the solutions on a larger data-set to see which solution is more performant.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8c05ed27e15fb2b46647a5503bfa9e1c)*

Answer (score 0):

You can try to avoid scalar subquery by using `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` function to get the `unique_id` you've started from. And do the same filtering based on maximum level found after the tree was build. Try this:

> ```
> with hier as (
>   select
>     /*Find unique ID of subtree*/
>     connect_by_root(f.unique_id) as unique_id,
>     connect_by_root(la.acct_code) as start_node,
>     la.acct_code,
>     /*Find max depth of subtree*/
>     max(level) over(partition by connect_by_root(f.unique_id)) as max_lvl,
>     /*Find current reversed depth of node*/
>     level as lvl
>   from linked_accounts la
>       left join test_data f
>         on la.acct_code = f.lookup_acct_code
>   start with f.unique_id is not null
>   connect by prior la.parent_code = la.acct_code
> )
> select
>   unique_id,
>   case max_lvl
>     when lvl
>     /*Select our start node for short subtree*/
>     then start_node
>     /*And node al level 3 otherwise*/
>     else acct_code
>   end as node_name
> from hier
> /*Select the node on level 3 from the root*/
> where max_lvl - lvl = 2
>   /*Or the last node in subtree for the depth < 3*/
>   or (max_lvl <= 2 and lvl = max_lvl)
> order by 1 asc
> ```
>
> ```
> UNIQUE_ID | NODE_NAME
> :-------- | :--------
> 1         | branch-1 
> 2         | branch-2 
> 3         | branch-1 
> 4         | trunk-2  
> 5         | root-1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c9786f40e5a1ae4deafdf76c0b359173)*